# How to handle karma/bower in a Symfony Bundle on github?

Tags: unit-testing, github, angularjs, symfony

i am working on a Symfony Bundle that uses angular among other javascript deps.
Now i want to unit-test my javascript code and i want to ship those tests as well.

My initial idea was to add bower.json and karma config to allow to run the tests if you check out the project.

But running the karma config would create a folder, and if you use the bundle as a vendor dependency, somewhere in a vendor subdir, you probably do not want the folder content to change right? That would lead to problems with composer and git since git would presume you want to commit changes to that dependency right?

So my Question is: How to properly handle karma and bower in a Symfony2 Bundle hosted on github?

Comment: Just add the created directories to gitignore.  And at least in my apps, the entire vendor directory is ignored as far as github is concerned.

Comment: @Cerad: So i use the Bundle directory but i ship the bundle with a gitignore file ignoring the dependencies - that's a good idea! why didn't i come up with that? :-)